# XAML - LayoutPanel The property 'Content' is set more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add two ComboBoxes inside a Layout Panel as shown in the code below.

But I am encountering an error - "The property 'Content' is set more than once". How do I add two combo boxes inside a Layout?

```
            <!--User Control Layout-->
        <dxdo:LayoutGroup x:Name="LayoutGroupTopLevel">
            <dxdo:LayoutGroup x:Name="GridViews" ItemWidth="1*" Orientation="Vertical" AllowClose="True" AllowDock="True" AllowFloat="True" AllowHide="True">

                <dxdo:LayoutPanel x:Name="Layers" Caption="User Control" ItemHeight="1*">
                 <dxdo:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Plan Type">
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Name="BoxEdit">
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="3 month"/>
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="2 year"/>
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>

                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Site">
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Name="BoxEdit1"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                  </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
                </dxdo:LayoutPanel>

                <dxdo:LayoutPanel x:Name="LayoutPanel" Caption="Properties" ItemHeight="1*">
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Site">
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" Name="ComboBoxEdit"/>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" Name="ComboBoxEdit1"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                </dxdo:LayoutPanel>

       </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
```

Can anyone please point out the mistake I am committing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using DevExpress WPF controls suite, your error is trying to add two `LayoutItem`s to a `LayoutPanel`. It only supports either a single `UIElement` or a `LayoutGroup` as content (see [LayoutPanel documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6823), section "Content"). So to complete your goal you should wrap the items with a `LayoutGroup`:

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel x:Name="Layers" (...)>
    <dxdo:LayoutGroup>
        <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Plan Type">(...)</dxlc:LayoutItem>
        <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Site">(...)</dxlc:LayoutItem>
    </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

**UPDATE**

As you pointed out (and it slipped my attention) you cannot directly add a `dxlc:LayoutItem` into a `dxdo:LayoutGroup`; you should wrap it in a `dxdo:LayoutControlItem` (again, it's all in the documentation):

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel x:Name="Layers" (...)>
    <dxdo:LayoutGroup>
        <dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Plan Type">(...)</dxlc:LayoutItem>
        </dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
        <dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Site">(...)</dxlc:LayoutItem>
        </dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
    </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

Alternatively, you can drop `dxlc:LayoutItem` altogether and use only `dxdo:LayoutControlItem` (use `Caption` property instead of `Label`):

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel x:Name="Layers" (...)>
    <dxdo:LayoutGroup>
        <dxdo:LayoutControlItem Caption="Plan Type">(...)</dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
        <dxdo:LayoutControlItem Caption="Site">(...)</dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
    </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

**CLARIFICATION**

To disambiguate:

- `xmlns:dxdo="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"`
- `xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"`

Comment: As u suggested I changed the code and I have edited it above as well. But I still get this error - "A value of type 'LayoutItem' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'BaseLayoutItemCollection'".

Comment: Yes I am using DevExpress WPF control suite.